# BinaryFormatter ignore assembly version

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-assembly, binaryformatter

I have the following method to generate a hash of an object. It works pretty good! But when I change the version of the assembly, the hash is changing even when the object is the same.

```
public static string GetHash(Object item)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, item);
    binaryFormatter.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;

    HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(memoryStream));
}
```

How is it possible to ignore the assembly version?

Comment: The object is *not* the same.  A type in .NET isn't just the namespace and type name, it also includes the assembly it came from.  Which includes the [AssemblyVersion].  A strong DLL-Hell counter-measure.  And a strong check that prevents deserializing data that no longer matches a changed class.  Your hash calculation just adds *another* check that the data has changed, possibly unnecessarily.  No, you can't ignore the assembly version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But when I change the version of the assembly, the hash is changing even when the object is the same.

yes, that is expected behaviour when using `BinaryFormatter`... it does not guarantee to create the same output - and *especially* since it includes full type information (including version) it is pretty much guaranteed to change between versions.

I would consider using a serializer that doesn't include type information; `XmlSerializer`, Json.NET or protobuf-net would leap to mind.

Answer (score 3):

[`BinaryFormatter.AssemblyFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.assemblyformat.aspx) is documented as:

> Gets or sets the behavior of the deserializer with regards to finding and loading assemblies.

There's no indication that it has an impact on the *serializing* path.

Personally I would avoid this method of hashing - it seems *terribly* fragile to me. Do you have no control over the object being hashed, or any way of hashing in a more stable way?